# file opening and writing in c

Tags: c, file

```
FILE *fp1;
if((fp1 = fopen("abc.txt", "w")) != NULL)
{
    fprintf(something);
    fclose(fp1);
}
```

I am trying to compile this file and all related file using developer command prompt and trying to run it from there. But while running it says this filename.exe has stopped working. It is not able to create the file abc.txt .

Comment: You need to show all the code—what is “something”?

Comment: Without a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard for us to say anything. And as SO isn't a debugger-as-a-service you should really [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And of course, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried `fprintf(fp1, something);`?

Comment: Well, let's think about this. You open `abc.txt` for **writing** (you don't use it in any way shown except `fclose`) and you `fprintf (something)` omitting the stream and passing an undefined `something`. That adds up to "stopped working" every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly don't have write permission in the directory you are attempting to create abc.txt in.  The code would be better if you handled the error case:

```
if ((fp1 = fopen("abc.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    perror("abc.txt");
    exit(1);
}
```

My guess is your output will be "abc.txt: Permission denied"

You also have a problem that your fprintf() ought to be fprintf(fp1, something) (where something is presumably your format string and some variables).

Comment: The fopen() ought to be creating the file.  If the file isn't being created, it is almost certainly the permissions (or a read-only file system, I suppose).  Since it's in the current directory, then it's not going to be a path error.

Comment: What was I thinking... You are one-step ahead. The permissions is a logical guess (although there isn't much to guess from in the question)